# AIR for iOS: create enterprise App without the certificate

Tags: iphone, ios, air, certificate, code-signing

We create for a cliet an enterprise Application using AIR for iOS.

Our client got an Enterprise Developper account. Is there a way to create the IPA file without the certificate, such that our client can sign it after it is built?

The question is how to create the final enterprise IPA if we do not want to provide the sourcecode (as this is not part of the deliverable) to our client and our client does not want to give the certificate out of their hands?

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe so, creating an IPA file requires a "Code signing Identity" witch is created with the certificate.

Comment: indeed. BUT actually there's an ugly way to achieve what you, Mat, desire: give them out compiled SWF and build script (Ant powered for example) so that IPA could be created on their side.